# Master password and Mergin Maps

Tags: mergin-maps

I made a shared map using the Mergin Maps plugin and for some reason one of the users is required to type a Masters Password.

I reviewed the most common issues found with the Master Password and one common solution seemed to remove the Mergin Maps configuration in the Authentication window or to untick the integrate master password with password manager.

However, QGIS still requires Master password for that one user. What is wrong? Why would it show Master password for that single user, is it something he accidentally activated and what should we do?

Comment: Could you please specify QGIS version, Mergin Maps plugin version and OS system?